# How to insert randomly entries of an array in another array react native

Tags: arrays, react-native

Let's says I have this array : `const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];`

And this array: `const letters = ['A','B','C'];`

I want to put *'letters'* entries inside *'numbers'* randomly. I don't care about the order of *'letters'*, but I want *'numbers'* to keep the order. The goal is to have this kind of array :

`const randomLettersInNumbers = [1, 'B', 2, 3, 'A', 4, 'C', 5];`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
const letters = ['A','B','C'];
let randomLettersInNumbers = numbers
letters.forEach((item) => {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomLettersInNumbers.length)
  randomLettersInNumbers.splice(index, 0, item)
})
```

Comment: Worked like charm, Thank you :)